# How to extract text at newline using regex pattern with python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My text is as follow:

```
"""
2.Consignee

VU TRINI GIA BAO SERVICE AND TRADING JOINY STOCK COMPANY
44/26 VO VAN DONG, STREET, O CHU DUA WARD



"""
```

What is the suitable regular expression pattern for me to extract out the value aft the title consignee?

Desired output:

```
VU TRINI GIA BAO SERVICE AND TRADING JOINY STOCK COMPANY
44/26 VO VAN DONG, STREET, O CHU DUA WARD
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be that generic, but I guess this gives what you expect:

```
print(re.sub("(?i)[. \n 0-9]*Consignee", "", re.sub("\n\n", "", text)))
```